# Redirect root query to another file not directoryindex with htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

I am sending query directly to my domain `example.com/?s=Xy1Ab` (S is something random and at 5 characters long like Xy1Ab) but I want my DirectoryIndex is index.html but I want to redirect this query string to index.php but it does not seem to work.

```
DirectoryIndex index.html
RewriteEngine   On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^s=(.*?){5}
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?s=%1? [R=302,L]
```

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: No error just goes to index.html, on LAMP and on local